# How to use Qmltermwidget

Tags: qt, github, terminal, qml

I would like to know how to use this [qmltermwidget GitHub](https://github.com/Swordfish90/qmltermwidget)
like how should I use it in a qt program whether I should 
include something like libs=-qmltermwidget in the .pro file or what should I do???

Comment: i need to add that program to my program how to do it??

Answer (score 1):

You can check how [`hawaii-desktop/hawaii-terminal`](https://github.com/hawaii-desktop/hawaii-terminal) includes `qmltermwidget`, since it is based on it, as [seen in its sources](https://github.com/hawaii-desktop/hawaii-terminal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=qmltermwidget).

It involves compiling the qmltermwidget sources through a [`plugin/qmltermwidget/qmltermwidget.pro`](https://github.com/hawaii-desktop/hawaii-terminal/blob/8c4701aa6e9223091ac3ad1fb0e8005c92399fee/plugin/qmltermwidget/qmltermwidget.pro) file (See [QT pro file Configuration Features](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#configuration-features))

Those sources are declared in the main project [`plugin/CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/hawaii-desktop/hawaii-terminal/blob/8c4701aa6e9223091ac3ad1fb0e8005c92399fee/plugin/CMakeLists.txt) file

```
add_subdirectory(qmltermwidget)
```

Comment: see the question its about qmltermwidget not qtermwidget

Comment: @dravigon I agree, but I suspect the general idea would still apply

Comment: @dravigon OK. I have edited the answer to reference another project which is using qmltermwidget as a plugin

Comment: wait i don't know how to use a plugin in qml

Comment: @dravigon http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html could help. As well as http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-qmlextensionplugins-example.html