# How to use a QML plugin

Tags: qt, plugins, qml

Can any one say the step by step method to incorporate already created plugins into a new QML based program.
I've got this plugin called qmltermwidget from git [qmltermwidget github](https://github.com/Swordfish90/qmltermwidget)
Now i have compiled it and I can test the example program in it but I don't know how to use it in my custom application using Qt/QML

Comment: The plugin needs to be in the list of plugin paths (see `QQmlEngine::addPluginPath`) and you simply import it and use it.

Comment: can you give a example??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[Creating C++ Plugins for QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html)".
In your case, you already have a plugin (from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42731833/6309)), but the steps involve:

- Write a project file for the plugin
- Create a **[qmldir file](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html)** to describe the plugin

> QML extension plugins are for either application-specific or library-like plugins.
>   Library plugins should limit themselves to registering types, as any manipulation of the engine's root context may cause conflicts or other issues in the library user's code.

The "[Module Definition qmldir Files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html)" is where you declare a plugin to be made available by the module.

```
plugin <Name> [<Path>]
```

> - `<Name>` is the plugin library name. This is usually not the same as the file name of the plugin binary, which is platform dependent; e.g. the library MyAppTypes would produce `libMyAppTypes.so` on Linux and `MyAppTypes.dll` on Windows.
> - `<Path>` (optional) specifies either:
>
>   - an absolute path to the directory containing the plugin file, or
>   - a relative path from the directory containing the qmldir file to the directory containing the plugin file.
>
> By default the engine searches for the plugin library in the directory that contains the `qmldir` file.
>   The plugin search path can be queried with [`QQmlEngine::pluginPathList()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#pluginPathList) and modified using [`QQmlEngine::addPluginPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addPluginPath).

Comment: again i don't get it i have he compiled plugin in a path say /QMLTermWidget in my main programs how should i add it to my main program

Comment: i have added the plugin folder to the qrc like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726321/load-qmldir-from-qrc-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the suggested answer does not work